AGrid Chekbox is working for child but not for the parent
Please Help. I am using dash agrid to create a Grid like this When i Have used agGroupCellRenderer for grouping . when i am clicking on the child checkbox it is working but when i am clicking on parent it is not working attaching the code .
import dash_ag_grid as dag
from dash import ( Dash,
    Input,
    Output,
    State,
    callback,
    ctx,
    html,
    no_update,
)

data =[
    {
      "statename": "All India",
      "districtcode": None,
      "districtname": None,
    },
    {
      "statename": "Gujarat",
      "districtcode": 462,
      "districtname": "Valsad"
    },
    {
      "statename": "Haryana",
      "districtcode": 58,
      "districtname": "Ambala"
    },
    {
      "statename": "Haryana",
      "districtcode": 59,
      "districtname": "Bhiwani"
    },
    {
      "statename": "Haryana",
      "districtcode": 701,
      "districtname": "Charki Dadri"
    },
    {
      "statename": "Haryana",
      "districtcode": 60,
      "districtname": "Faridabad"
    },
    {
      "statename": "Haryana",
      "districtcode": 61,
      "districtname": "Fatehabad"
    },]
app = Dash()


columndefs = [
    {
     "field": "statename", "rowGroup": True, "hide": True , "checkboxSelection":True,
     
    }
 ]
options = {
        "autoGroupColumnDef":{
            "headerName": "State/District",
            "field": "districtname",
            "cellRenderer": "agGroupCellRenderer",
            "cellRendererParams": {"checkbox":True,"suppressCount": True},
            "headerCheckboxSelectionCurrentPageOnly": True,
        },
       
    }

app.layout = html.Div([dag.AgGrid(
        id="tab2-state-district-grid",
        className="ag-theme-balham",
        rowData=data,
        columnDefs=columndefs,
        dashGridOptions=options,
        defaultColDef=dict(
            resizable=False,
            flex=1,
            suppressSizeToFit=True,
            suppressMovable=True,
            floatingFilter=False,
            filter=False,
        ),
        enableEnterpriseModules=True,
        licenseKey="LICENSE_KEY_HERE",
        persistence=True,
        persistence_type="session",
        persisted_props=["selectedRows"],
    ),
    html.H1(id="data-dd")]
)

@callback(
    [
        Output("data-dd", "children"),
    ],
    [
       Input("tab2-state-district-grid", "selectedRows"),   
       Input("tab2-state-district-grid", "cellClicked"),


    ],
)
def test_grid(selcted_rows,cell_click):
    print(ctx.triggered_id,"selcted_rows",selcted_rows)
    print(ctx.triggered_id,"cell_click",cell_click)
    return no_update


app.run(debug=True)

Please Help.
I want that when i am clicking on parent it should give me parent name when i am clicking on child checkbox it should give parent name and childname .
